# How to UPDATE WordPress data using query

Tags: wordpress

I am now making a BD police law exam , I want to add exam counting system but my code not working properly, I'm Mysql beginner.

```html
$charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();
$variable211 = $wpdb->prefix . "exam_count";        
$variable2111 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $variable211 (
    id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    countt DOUBLE NOT NULL
) $charset_collate;";
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
dbDelta( $variable2111 );
```

This my code:

```html
$myrows1 = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $variable211 WHERE id=1" );
$count=$myrows1->countt;
$count=$count+1;
if(!$myrows1){
    $sql1 = $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( "INSERT INTO $variable211 ( countt) VALUES ( %f ) ",1));
}else{
    $sql2= $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( "UPDATE INTO SELECT * FROM $variable211 WHERE ID = 1 ( countt ) VALUES ( %f )",$count));               
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
global $wpdb;
$myrows1 = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $variable211 WHERE id=1" );
$count=$myrows1->countt;
$count=$count+1;
if(!$myrows1){
 $sql1 = $wpdb->insert(
  $variable211,
  array(
   'countt' => '1'
  ),
     array(  
      '%d'
     )
 );
}
else{
 $sql2 = $wpdb->update(
  $variable211,
  array(
   'countt' => $count
  ),
  array(
   'ID' => '1'
  ),
     array(  
      '%d'
     )
 );
}
```